# Changing path for custom build step

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have inherited a visual studio 2003 project which uses some custom build steps.  I'm having some trouble with the path to the tool.  Where does visual studio get its PATH?  I've echoed out %PATH% in the custom build step and it has no resemblance to the system path.  I did find a value in the registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\VC\VC_OBJECTS_PLATFORM_INFO\Win32\Directories

Path Dirs which looked like it might be the path used by visual C but chaning it doesn't seem to alter the path in VC.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio has the annoying habit of 'playing' with your path, which leads to the effect you've seen.

The easiest way to work around it *if* you're willing to change the environment inside VS (which will change it for all your projects) would be to go to Tools > Options > Projects > VC++ Directories and add the required directories to the appropriate setting - in your case that should be 'Executable files'.

Another method I am using if I don't want to change the overall environment is to create a batch file that first calls vsvars32.bat for the appropriate compiler version, then manipulate the PATH variable and finally starts 'devenv'. I actually prefer this approach but it means your disk is littered with small batch files that you'll only use to kick off Visual Studio...